# if statement in ruby loop editing properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two database tables, user and product
When the user creates a product the user.id is placed into the product table under product.user_id

I'm writing a loop to displays all products "belonging" to the currently signed in user, it looks like this so far.

```
<% @product.each do |p| %>
 <% if product.user_id = user.id %>
 <tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= product.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= product.id %></td>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
</tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If the currently signed in user is user 2 for example, instead of filtering all products that don't have a user.id of 2 it just changes the product.user_id for every product to 2 so that the returned table looks like so.

```
2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 2 4
```

Without the if statement it returns the full product listing with all the correct properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your complete solution

```
<% @product.each do |p| %>
 <% if p.user_id == user.id %>
 <tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= p.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= p.id %></td>
    <td><%= p.name %></td>
</tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However I don't know what is going on in your controller but you could probably save a lot of effort by filtering out on the current user's products in the controller prior to serving that `@product` instance variable to the view. Maybe try a query like this:

```
user_id = current_user.id #assuming you have access to a method like this
@product = Product.where(user_id: user_id)
```

**EDIT**
philomor is correct. You should add a has many relationship on user see below.

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

However not that you have this relationship you want to be carful that when you call it you don cause an [N+1 query](https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/). To avoid this do the following when fetching all of a user’s products

```
@products = User.find(params[:user_id]).includes(:products).products
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for that, I was sure I could do something like this on the controller level but wasn't sure how to implement it, this is very helpful!

Comment: Honestly, you should probably have a `has_many :products` in your User model, and a `belongs_to :user` in your product model. Then you could just write `@products = user.products`.

Comment: Thanks so much you two, code was working with the original solution from Strife but I'll refactor it so that it's more efficient (I already had those relationships set up in my models, but had no idea how to leverage them)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `==` not `=`:

```
<% if product.user_id == user.id %>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!
I knew it would be something way too simple.

Answer (score -1):

Use a comparison operator `==` and your if statement should be something like

```
<% if p.user_id = user.id %>
```